# provider: SNI_PN11, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, asp.net-core-6.0

I m trying to run this this command for scaffolding the db context in SQL Server 2022 using .NET Core 6:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=IN-PG0351TV\MSSQLSERVER;Database=LearnDB;Trusted_Connection=True;" 
         Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
         -OutputDir Models
```

But I get this error:

> Error Number:87,State:0,Class:20
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

I have checked my server and instance name are correct. My instance is also running

Comment: You are using the visual studio's local DB to test or you have installed the sql server inside the machine and do some test?

Comment: `MSSQLSERVER` is typically the name of the **default** instance - which you connect to *without* specifying the instance name - try to use `Server=IN-PG0351TV;Database=LearnDB;Trusted_Connection=True;` as your connection string